# Getting Google referrer link in PHP from Ajax searches

Tags: php, ajax

I log all the referrers to my site in PHP, and this always worked great. Now I noticed today that there were a lot of referrers from Google base domains like https://www.google.com

Of course there are no links to my site from that frontpage, so I started to do some research.

I log the referrer with this: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` which works fine, most of the time.

But in Google Chrome, using the new standard Google Ajax pages, it doesn't show the full referral link anymore.

So instead of showing this:

> https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=this+is+a+query&oq=this+is+a+query&gs_l=hp.3..33i29l4.19228.20509.0.21050.15.12.0.2.2.3.204.1289.7j4j1.12.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.WZ-VpIRpJ0o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.d2k&fp=4af21ea2c089d08b&biw=1920&bih=922

It shows

> https://www.google.com/

in my referral logs.

Is there anyway I can still get the full referral link when those Ajax type Google searches are performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From April 2012 you can expect to see faster click through from Google search results as the search engine switches to the “referrer” meta tag to handle the referring URL from organic search results. The feature will be available only in browsers which support it (e.g. Chrome) [1](http://dejanseo.com.au/google-to-change-http-referrer/).

https

Webmaster will start seeing Google homepage as origin referrer and source of organic traffic via SSL.
refrecne:[Google to Change HTTP Referrer](http://dejanseo.com.au/google-to-change-http-referrer/)

Comment: So with this new change, it is impossible for me to get the used keywords directly in PHP? I target my ads around the used keywords now, so this information is very useful to me, and I'm sure, many other webmasters.

Comment: after this google use a interface page beetwen searching page and target page;in this page empty value of q then redirct to Target page thus you cannor finde user query

Answer (score -1):

I also think that from 2012 you can expect to see faster click through from Google search results as the search engine switches to the referrer meta tag:[1](http://lioa.net) to handle the referring URL from organic search results.